# Accessing struct member name in C using Macros

Tags: c++, c, macros, struct

I have some problem with using Macros in C. I need to access the struct member's name. And I found a solution of it in C++ from this link [HERE!!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452112/how-to-get-struct-member-with-a-string-using-macros-c). Now I'm trying to translate it to C, but I can't have the function in struct.
This is the only thing I can do :

```
typedef struct ms ms;
struct ms{
#define SM(y, z) z y;
SM(author, char*);
SM(title, char*);
SM(year, int);
void (*set)(char* fname, char* val);
#undef SM
};
```

Then, the function :

```
void set(char* fname, char* val)
{
   //code
}
```

But I don't know how should I fill in the code in function to get the same solution as the link I mentioned before. I need help :( anyone?

Comment: I would say that everything mentioned in that link falls under the category "very bad practice, never do this". Re-inventing the programming language with macros is always a really bad idea. Not only is it incredibly error-prone because of the non-existent type safety, but it is also an unreadable mess for other programmers. Other programmers know C, they do not know "Bob's private little macro language".

Comment: Also, if you only know about function pointers, you can achieve my_struct.set_var() in a far better and cleaner way. Or even better, design C modules based on incomplete type, which is essentially the C version of object-oriented design.

Comment: What is the original problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Lundin wow, thanks for the information. I really don't know about this. I just discover macros yesterday because I found that link that looks good for my problem. Actually I need to convert an XML file (not XSD) automatically to C struct. I have post a question about it, but hasn't been solved yet. My idea is, if I can access the struct member by its name using string example:  `set("author","John");`
I can convert it automatically (if the XML element name change, I don't have to change the code), because the struct is generated automatically by gSOAP also (the members name = elements name)

Comment: You've really don't need the semicolon at the end of the macro definition as you end up with two semi-colons in a row within the structure definition.

Comment: @user2809943 Are all entries strings, or are there integers etc as well? (If they are all strings, then you don't even need a struct, just an array of char pointers)

Comment: @Lundin No, there are some other data types. And it should be in struct. Any suggestion? This problem is really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

The strings will have to be copied using `strcpy`.  So, `author` field will get populated as

```
struct ms myvar;

#define setstr(author,val) strcpy ( (myvar.author), val )
```

`int` can be assigned just regularly

```
#define setint(year,val) myvar.year=val
```

Comment: Thanks, this is somehow giving some inspiration, but I need to access (in main func) the member by string. It's like 
`set("author","John");` something like that.

Comment: Then, you will have to modify your macro to recognize that you are trying to modify the field `"author"` and then, modify `myvar.author` or whatever other field you are trying for.

Comment: yees I know, but, to implement it is kinda confusing for me. I just discovered Macros like 2-3 days ago. And I knew nothing about it. How it works is a bit confusing.