# How to convert a string variable name into a the value of the variable

Tags: c++

- I have a class with double members:

  `double price;
  double kg;
  etc.`
- I have a vector of strings that contains the names of the members:

  `vector<string> vec = {"price", "kg", etc};`
- I want to retrieve the one of the values by passing its name to a `getValue()` method:

  `double answer = getValue(vec[0]);`
- So I wonder how to convert the name of the member into the value of that member?

Comment: What value should `"price"` be?

Comment: In the vector of string, "price" will be "price". In the class, price=3.5 for example.

Comment: can you protoype some code and show it? It's easier to read and help you if you already have something.

Comment: The name of a variable isn't accessible to the program. You need to do that mapping yourself.

Comment: You're looking for the [std::stod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/) function (convert a string to a double.)

Comment: it seems more like a named-enum or similar is needed. maybe use a map instead of an vector or just enums instead of strings (or some string-enum mapping) but hard to see what is needed without actual code

Comment: Unless this is for a class in which you are learning C++ (which is OK), C++ may be the wrong language for you. That being said:  If you do a google search for "C++ parse string to double" or "C++ convert string to double"  you will get lots of suggestions, most of which use the standard library function std::stod().

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? `if( vec[0] == "price" ) return price; else if( vec[0] == "kg" ) return kg;`

Comment: Hi Chris Stathis, no, the vector has string word, so I can't convert it into double with std.

Comment: Chris and I are right.  std::stod is what you are looking for.  Its entire purpose in life is to convert strings (what you are calling words) into doubles.  The strings have to LOOK like numbers: i.e "1.25" works.   "one and a quarter" does not work.

Comment: Hi Peter G.,  your idea is good. My problem is that I have 100 item in my vector and I do not want to do 100 time: if( vec[0] == "price" ) return price; if( vec[1] == "kg" ) return price; if( vec[100] == "the100th" ) return price;

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to do reflection. It's not very easy to do this in C++. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452112/how-to-get-struct-member-with-a-string-using-macros-c) may be of use. You'd have to modify it slightly to match your requirements

Comment: Hi Dale,  but my string has  "one and a quarter", not 3.4, so it will not work.

Comment: cabe you should use an map with string as key and the double as value (`std::map<std::string,double>`). So you can just do something like `return values["price"]`. I could type the details as an answer but it also seems like some good c++ pratice to do it yourself

Comment: Hi Hayt, yes I guess this is the smartest solution. Thanks to you and all the other for you help.

Comment: Hi Hayt, to fill the map I have still have to do: map[vec[0]]=price; map[vec[1]]=kg; ...map[vec[100]]=the100th; So I still have to do that 100 times. Do you have something more fast? Like a convertion btw string "identifier" into double "identifier" so that I can do that in a loop? Regards

Answer (score 1):

First of all, recognize that this is not easy.   At runtime C++ has no information at all about the names of variables, etc.  If you really need that information often, consider using another language such as C# or Java, or any of the other languages that support reflection.

That being said:

It appears that you want to select a variable by providing a text string that identifies it.  A straight series of

```
double getValue(const string &name)
{
   if( name == "name1")
      return name1;
   if(name == "name2")
      return name2;
   return not_found_value;
}
```

is not a bad choice.

However if you want to make it more complicated but make the `getValue` code more efficient:

```
enum Names
{
  NAME1, NAME2, ...NAMEN
};
typedef std::map<std::string, Names> StringToEnum;
StringToEnum stringToEnum;
void initialize()
{
    stringToEnum["name1"] = NAME1;
    etc for names 2 through N
}

double getValue(const string &name)
{
   auto found = stringToEnum.find(name);
   if(found != stringToEnum.end())
   {
     switch(found->second)
     {
        case NAME1: return name1;
        case NAME2: return name2;
        etc.
     }
   }
   return notFoundValue;
}
```

Sorry this is ugly, but it *is* slightly more efficient because the map lookup is quicker than a series of string compares.  It would be even more efficient if your vector stored the enum values rather than text strings (you could write another method to translate the enums back to text strings if you need to.)

Having said all of this about efficiency, let me mention that you probably don't need it to be efficient! If efficiency is critical, you would be better off redesigning your program so that there is no need to identify variables by name.

With that in mind, I recommend the simplest and most straightforward code.  The chain of if's is the "right" answer because it makes it very obvious what is happening.